# JCheckBox selection

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcheckbox

This is a snippet from a JCheckBox list. I need to capture events of items checked .
As of now it is only selecting list code which is highlighted

```
private class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

    public ControlPanel() {
        this.add(new JLabel("Selection:"));
        this.add(new JButton(new SelectionAction("Clear", false)));
        this.add(new JButton(new SelectionAction("Check", true)));
    }
}

private class SelectionAction extends AbstractAction {

    boolean value;

    public SelectionAction(String name, boolean value) {
        super(name);
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if (selectionModel.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                dataModel.setValueAt(value, i, CHECK_COL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: LOL. How many acronyms have you invented yet?

Comment: @JBNizet  I didn't invent that one.  It came out of edits for the MCVE (minimal complete valid example) which I did coin.

Comment: I fugured it out guys ,had to update logic in actionPerformed